# how do delete complex duplicate columns

Tags: unix

```
  Date              ID     S_count U_count
09/01/13 12:00 AM    23    30      0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    2       0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    4992    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     1036    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     5600    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    23    37      0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    1       0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    4905    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     1230    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    0       2
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     0       1036
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    0       1
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     0       1230
09/01/13 02:00 AM    27    0       1
09/01/13 02:00 AM    8     0       1477
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     5401    0
```

Output will be like :

```
Date                 ID    S_count U_count
09/01/13 12:00 AM    23    30      0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    2       0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    4992    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8    1036     0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8    5600     0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    23    37      0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    1       0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    4905    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8    1230     0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8    5401     0
```

There are many more record like this .. I want to delete those rows which is duplicate. S_count values some where similar to U_count values. So need to delete U_count rows. 
Note: both time and ID's are same for S_count and U_count.

Comment: If you fix the format, someone might look twice at this question.

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1 || ($6==0)' inputfile
  Date              ID     S_count U_count
09/01/13 12:00 AM    23    30      0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    2       0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    4992    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     1036    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     5600    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    23    37      0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    1       0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    4905    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     1230    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     5401    0
```

Answer (score 0):

**One more simple way with awk**

```
awk -F " " '$5>0' temp.txt
```

**Output:**

```
09/01/13 12:00 AM    23    30      0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    2       0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    27    4992    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     1036    0
09/01/13 12:00 AM    8     5600    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    23    37      0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    1       0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    27    4905    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     1230    0
09/01/13 01:00 AM    8     5401    0
```